# How to display images dynamically one after another

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I am working on asp.net and i am new for it. I have been given a task where i have to display the history of any object. The object tranfered at many location and its location is tracked from DB.
by current_location column.
There are 3 locations like 1. outside 2. Inside  3. Ocupied.

What i have to do is whenever any user click on object history. Then it must show all it's history with 3 images (outside.png,inside.png, occupied.png).

I mean lets say first the object was outside then inside then occupied then the history must be displayed by images like:

`Outside.png ->Inside.png->Occupied.png`  It must be done using html, javascript and c# only.

How to do it any idea ? I just need the logic to do it ?

Comment: should image change after certain interval or on click? u looking solution in plain JS  or you are allowed to use jQuery?

Comment: I am alowed to use jquery. and image do not change after any interval. ITS JUST LIKE displaying history of objects by displaying some static images of all the departments. and the list of each transfer will come from DB. like transfer 1 was outside, transfer 2 was inside, transfer 3 was occupied, then transfer 4 was again inside. so i will have 3 images for eac department and in this case and we will have to display liek this: outside.png->inside.png->occupied.png->inside.png

Comment: i can use anything in asp.net to make it happen. But remember that the list of tarnsaction of object will come from DB and image will be decided by me (i mean this thing i have to decide by my code either in c#/js/jquery that in case the current location is outside then i have to display outside.png).

Answer (score 0):

```
string []images = new string [] { "<img src=\"Outside.png\">", "<img src=\"Inside.png\">", "<img src=\"Occupied.png\">" };
SqlConnection dbconn = new SqlConnection ("user id=username;" + 
        "password=password;server=serverurl;database=database;"
        ); //change username, password, serverurl, and database to what you use to connect to your database
dbconn.Open ();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand ("SELECT current_location FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE THING=",dbconn); //change TABLE_NAME to the name of your table, and change "WHERE THING=" to what you use to specify which thing
SqlReader reader = command.ExecuteReader ();
while (reader.Read ())
{
    Response.Write (images [reader.GetInt32(0)]);
}
```

Comment: i understand nothing from ur answer. please read carefully my question carefully and answer me with entire explanation.

Comment: If I am right, you want to see the status of a thing in the web page. And the thing has 3 statuses: outside, inside, and occupied. And you want to see the status as an image. When the status of the thing changes, you want the picture in the web page to change without need to refresh the page. So you need ajax. Every time check_history.aspx is requested, it should read the database and find out the status of the thing, then it outputs either "Outside,png", "Inside.png", or "Occupied.png" (the string, not the content of the pictures).

Comment: ITS  has to be like displaying history of objects by displaying some static images of all the departments.so that the one would be able to know where the object was previously and where it is currently and the list of each transfer will come from DB. like transfer 1 was outside, transfer 2 was inside, transfer 3 was occupied, then transfer 4 was again inside. so i will have 3 images for each department and in this case and we will have to display like this: outside.png->inside.png->occupied.png->inside.png

Comment: Do you have several rows in the database, each for a transfer? Do you need a new image to appear when there is a new transfer without refreshing the page?

Comment: yes thats true that there are several rows  corrsponding to the each transfer of object from one location of image to another (i am currently taking 3 locations only: Inside, outside, Occupied). for example if  i  have to see the current history of my object and it was previously "Outside" and transferred to Inside in second row(1 row for each transfer, having a column showing  its current location as inside because its current location is "Inside"). Now in this case the history must display : Outside.png->Inside.png

Comment: What is the type of column current_location? 1, 2, 3 or Outside, Inside, Occupied?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: i am using sqlserver . and yes you can assume the location type to 1, 2, 3 so that in our case wheever we find he current location to 2 and its previous location to 1. That mean that row signifies that we have to display of object from Outside.png to (->) Inside.png in our our display. Understood ? please let me know if any other doubt